# How to fade in / fade out an arbitrary number of UIImages in a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, core-animation

Seeking general advice.  I have an arbitrary number of `UIImages`s with references stored in an array.  I want the first image to fade out completely, then the next image to fade in, stay for a couple seconds, and then fade out.  And so on for each image in the array.  So, the animation is cycling through a number of views where each view fades out, then fades in the next one.  The animation repeats indefinitely.  I hope I'm being clear.  I do not want a cross-dissolve transition where one images fades into another.

Ideally, I'd like to use the same `UIImageView` and just replace the image once the previous image has faded out (i.e. alpha property set to 0.0).

I'm curious the best way to achieve this, and if I should use `UIView`'s animation methods or use Core Animation.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
NSArray* images.. //some initialization code somewhere at your class
NSUInteger currentIndex = 5; //lets assume you have some property for storing your current image index

-(void)animateToImageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)targetIndex{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1.0 options:nil animations:^{
        yourImageView.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        yourImageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:++currentIndex];
        yourImageView.alpha = 1.0;
        if(currentIndex < targetIndex){
            [self animateToImageAtIndex:targetIndex];
        }
    }];
}
```

then when you need it just call `[self animateToImageAtIndex:*someTargetIndex*];`
Note however that this code have no check routines for bounds of a data array, as it's depends on concrete implementation of the storage.

Comment: hey you beat me by 36 seconds :)

Comment: I guess, I've seen the question a little bit earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

Have not tested, but something like this should do it:

```
-(void)imageAnimation{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        myImageView.alpha = 1.0;
   } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:2.0 options:nil animations:^{
             myImageView.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
             myImageView.image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex%[imgArray count]];
             currentIndex++;
             [self imageAnimation];
        }];
   }];
 }
```